# Getting output layer neuron values for Spark ML Multilayer Perceptron Classifier

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am doing binary classification using Spark ML Multilayer Perceptron Classifier.

```
mlp = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(labelCol="evt", featuresCol="features", layers=[inputneurons,(inputneurons*2)+1,2])
```

The output layer has of two neurons as it is a binary classification problem. Now I would like get the values two neurons for each of the rows in the test set instead of just getting the prediction column containing either 0 or 1.

I could not find anything to get that in the API document.

Comment: Optimally, shouldn't the size of your hidden layer be in between the size of input layer and the size of output layer?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier), Spark ML package does offer MLP (Multilayer Perceptron) as classifier only (no regression), and as a result it pushes output layer values to a softmax function to generate binary output value:

> Nodes in the output layer use softmax function