# Does pyspark ml support Ann regressors?

Tags: pyspark, neural-network, regression

Have checked the documentation of pyspark ml but it seems that an Ann regressor is not available so if my output needs to be a continuous value Is there any other way to go about it in pyspark ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113393/pyspark-getting-output-layer-neuron-values-for-spark-ml-multilayer-perceptron-c : ML package does offer MLP (Multilayer Perceptron) as classifier only (no regression) and as a result it pushes output layer values to a softmax function to generate binary output value.

Comment: So if I want a continuous value as an output , I will not be able to use pyspark ml I’m guessing